# MySQLi results disappear on webserver, but stick on localhost

Tags: php, mysqli

I have no idea what's happening.

So on local host, everything loads perfectly fine:

[Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbzcL.png)

and this is the code for connecting:

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$dbname = 'x';
$password = '';
```

and on the webserver, it does not:

[Webserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCllV.png)

and this is the code for the webserver:

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'parawtme_root';
$dbname = 'parawtme_xx';
$password = 'password_goes_here';
```

This is the only different bit in the code. Literally. What am I doing wrong?

My fetch script:

```
<?php
$sql = "$getdb
WHERE $tablenames.$pricename LIKE 'M9%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo $tableformat;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    include 'var.php';
    echo $dbtable;
}
   echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Could it be do to a difference in different PHP servers?

Thanks.

Comment: Turn on error reporting and check what is the error,It might be database connection issue as some server does not take `localhost` as hostname

Comment: Error reporting is already on though.

Comment: I would suggest turning on the mysql server errors using mysqli_connect_error() . After the mysqli_connect use mysqli_connect_error() to print out any errors. And also check if the table is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check `connection` error and `mysqli` query `error`

```
    <?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'parawtme_root';
$dbname = 'parawtme_xx';
$password = 'password_goes_here';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    $sql = "$getdb
    WHERE $tablenames.$pricename LIKE 'M9%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo $tableformat;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        include 'var.php';
        echo $dbtable;
    }
       echo "</table>";

    } else {
        echo "0 results "; print_r(mysqli_error($conn));die;
    }
    ?>
```